# How to check the end of nested forEach loops

Tags: javascript

```
A.forEach((a, i) =>
  a.B.forEach((b, j) =>
    b.C.forEach((c, k) => {
      // most inner loop logic
      // something like console.log(A[i].B[j].C[k])
      if (/* condition */) {
        // execute once at the end
      }
    })
  )
);
```

I am trying to execute some commands after looping through all parent array children, I tried playing with the condition but I couldn't reach the desired result so far.

How should we approach this?

Comment: please add `A` and what you like to achieve.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "execute once at the end"?  If you want something to happen after `A.forEach()` completes then wouldn't you put it *after* the call to `A.forEach()`?

Comment: I think the OP wants to know when he's on the last element in the recursive loop. Essentially when `i === A.length-1 && j === a.B.length-1 && k === b.C.length-1`. But it's hard to tell.

Comment: @NinaScholz A, B, and C are all arrays of objects, I assumed this can be inferred from using `forEach` on them. After looping through all array items and reaching the final most inner child, I would like to execute some code.

Comment: @David If you are looping through a large array the computation could take some time, which means that the block after `A.forEach()` may execute -and even complete- while the loop is still running (parallel), this could lead to some issues especially if the next block is using a modified version of `A`, which is why the loop is there in the first place.

Comment: @ktilcu Prickly, yes. Does the condition you provided satisfy that? can't tell without testing it, will do in a minute.

Comment: @user5470921: Since when is `Array.prototype.forEach` asynchronous?  Is that new?  Or are you using a different `.forEach()` that you're not specifying in the question?

Comment: @user5470921 yeah it should work.

Comment: @David I have encountered this problem many times before, but I could be mistaken. Are you telling me that the program would keep running the loop until it reaches its end, "then" after that the next block would be executed? So if I was modifying all `A[i].B[j].C[k]`, that would be reflected in the next block and nothing would reach the next block unmodified?

Comment: @user5470921: If the code is blocking, and to my knowledge `Array.prototype.forEach` is, then the code will execute statements in the exact order in which they are written.

Comment: @David What do you mean by "blocking", can you further elaborate?

Comment: @user5470921: By "blocking" I mean "synchronous".  *Most* code is synchronous.  Unless you're performing an asynchronous operation, your code will execute in the exact order in which you've written it.  To my knowledge, `Array.prototype.forEach` is *not* asynchronous.  Do you have code which demonstrates otherwise?

Comment: @David Interesting, I don't at the moment but I have always treated it this way, async or semi-async, because sometimes -most of the times- it behaves correctly especially if the loop is minimal, not the case for large arrays though. I remember clearly a time where I was facing some issues with the a block after the loop being executed before the loop was fully executed. Adding a condition similar to my question fixed that, it always does, this time the condition was a bit challenging for me for some reason, probably due to a lick of sleep.

Comment: @ktilcu Just tested it, it works, can you post the solution as an answer so that I can pin it? thanks.

Comment: Thanks user5470921 I'm fine with @basti having it. Glad we could help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks a bit dirty but might fulfil your needs

```
A.forEach((a, i) =>
  a.B.forEach((b, j) =>
    b.C.forEach((c, k) => {
      // most inner loop logic
      // something like console.log(A[i].B[j].C[k])
      if (i === A.length-1 &&
          j === a.B.length-1 &&
          k === b.C.length-1) {
        // execute once at the end
      }
    })
  )
);
```

Comment: Will test it, but from first glance I don't think that `a.length-1` would do it, because that value would change in each loop.

Comment: no, it is the size of your list. it's fixed for each loop. only i j k are changing.

Comment: It should be `i === A.length - 1`, just tested it.

Comment: Sure, sorry, typo.